# Boostrap dropdown - mostrar item seleccionado

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-3

tengo este código dentro de un modal de boostrap que genera un dropdown con 2 items, lo que no consigo hacer es que al seleccionar uno de ellos se quede marcado en el dropdown.

Tengo este código

```
    <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Desde plantilla
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Coches</button>
                <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Motos</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Me genera esto por pantalla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado capturar el evento de esta forma, sin éxito

```
    $("#dropdownMenu2").on('click', 'li a', function(){
        alert('entro opción 1');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#dropdownMenu2','li a', function(event) {
        alert('entro opción 2');
    });
```

Gracias

Comment: A qué te refieres con marcado?, Que quede como texto visible del dropdown?

Comment: Exacto que si selecciono Motos se quede marcado al hacer click

Comment: Ok, ¿nos compartes que has intentado?, esto parece trabajarse con JS

Comment: Edito el primer post, gracias @BetaM

Answer (score 1):

El dropdown de bootstrap no es un reemplazo de un `select`. Es más bien como para seguir ligas. Si es verdad que puedes añadirle con CSS el que se vea COMO un Select, pero no es lo mismo.

Lo primero que te recomendaría, es usar un `select` con la clase `form-control` es bastante agradable a la vista.

Ahora, si forzosamente quieres que se cambie el texto de `Desde la plantilla` por `motos`, por ejemplo, como te han dicho arriba, es un caso para Javascript

Esta es una solución super sucia para la opción de las motos, pero te da la idea:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="dropdown-item" type="button" >Coches</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item" 
        type="button"
        onclick="document.getElementById('dropdownMenu2').innerHTML = 'Motos'">
        Motos
    </button>
</div>
```

Aunque insisto, lo más limpio sería usar un `<select class="form-control">`.